# Is there a way to tell a python function received a default value or keyword parameter?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, keyword

```
def func(a, b = 100):
  return a + b

func(a)
func(a,b = 100)
```

Is there any way to tell when func is called, b value 100 is taken from the default or  keyword parameter?

Comment: A lot of the answers look eerily familiar to a [certain article](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Default_Argument_Values#Default_Argument_Values) I've read somewhere...This is probably a [Good Thing](http://catb.org/jargon/html/G/Good-Thing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not as you've written your code. However, you can do:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = 100
    return a + b
```

Comment: How do yo kow if None was passed or not?

Comment: Passing `None` is the same as not passing anything.

Comment: No, **you cannot differentiate the two cases** is the correct way to describe what happens. I'm saying that, if you need to differentiate that, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: calling `func(a_var)` is equivalent to calling `func(a_var, None)`.

Comment: If you **really** need to know, then you need to make the default something that can't possibly be passed in, by packaging up the function in such a way that the caller doesn't have access to the default value.

Comment: @Droogans how so? If we do `def f(a=5): return a` and call `f(None)`, we still get `None` back. It would be nice if Python did replace `None`s, though...

Answer (score 4):

An anonymous object is the way to go to cover all possible cases.

```
def foo(a, b=object()):
    if b is foo.func_defaults[0]:
         # no value was passed
    # do whatever
```

Comment: Clever, but if I saw this in real code it would most definitely make me scratch my head.

Comment: @AdamParkin Yes, in 90% cases (or more), the `None` solution will be "better", just because it is easier to understand. If I was reviewing the code I posted in real world, I would demand either an approach with `None` or *a justification for why this specific approach is necessary*. But it's still the solve-it-all hammer approach, nonetheless and may have been the solution if the OP needed the solve-it-all hammer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really func's business to know.  But you can default to `None` instead.

```
def func(a, b=None):
  if b is None:
    # b = default b
    b = 100
  return a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object as the default value, e.g.

```
dummy = object()

def func(a, b=dummy):
  used_default = b is dummy
  if used_default:
    b = 100
  print used_default

func(0)           # prints True
func(0, None)     # prints False
func(0, object()) # prints False
```

Comment: [Do not use mutable objects as default values in the function or method definition](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Default_Argument_Values#Default_Argument_Values).

Comment: Fine, use an immutable object. It doesn't matter since it's a dummy object that you wouldn't do anything with.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. You are testing if the `id` matches. The link I left you is more about passing in empty lists, to be used later in the function.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to check if `b` matches a *default* value exactly, then don't use a default value! If you absolutely have to leave `b` optional, pass a special value (perhaps `-1`) to denote an unusual case, and be sure to note this in your `__doc__`. Just make sure that you're not able to reach the exceptional value in any day-to-day use, and that the exceptions written to contain that logic do not modify sensitive areas of your code.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other suggestions is to use a `kwargs` parameter and then do something like this:

```
def func(a, **kwargs):
if 'b' in kwargs:
    print 'b was passed in'
    b = kwargs['b']
else:
    print 'b was not passed in'
    b = 100

return a + b


a = 50
func(a)
func(a, b = 100)
```

Output:

```
b was not passed in
150
b was passed in
150
```

Because `kwargs` is a dictionary containing all non-optional parameters you can examine this dictionary to determine what was/wasn't passed.

You can make the lookup of `b` more efficient rather then looking up `kwargs` twice if needed.